# Post Hoc for Fisher's Exact Test on a 5x5 table

Tags: sas, post-hoc, fishers-exact-test

I have two nominal variables which are site (location) and Depression Scores (PHQ-9). I have found a significant association after running a Fisher's Exact Test (with monte carlo approximation) on a 5x5 table.

I realize that this test only tells me that there is some kind of association b/w site and depression scores. I'm wondering now if there are any post-hoc tests I can run. I would like to conclude that higher depression scores (indicative of more severe depression) is associated with a specific site, but can I actually conclude that from the Fisher's Exact Test? If not, what tests can I run to see if this is true and conclusively say this?

Comment: If your depression scores are nominal, how can you tell which score indicates severe depression.  Since you say you want to identify the site with more severe depression, you must have at least an ordinal scale.  That would mean you could do tests other than a Fisher's Exact Test. Pls clarify your scale.  Also, what size groups do you have data on?

Comment: Sorry, the depression scores are ordinal not nominal!! My mistake. Since they are ordinal, what can I conclude from my Fisher's test? Can I actually say that site A is associated with higher depression scores (or more severe depression)?

Comment: Pls clarify your scale. Also, what size groups do you have data on?